# how to solve this complex if-statement in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I need to exclude elements from a function and am struggling with the if-clause...

I can have four type of elements with three attributes

```
             A                  B               C          D
-----------------------------------------------------------------
"external"   undefined     boolean/undefined   boolean     boolean
"wrapper"    boolean       undefined           boolean     undefined
"parent"     1             0                   1          1
```

I need to construct an if-clause that only allows **A** and **B** to pass and I'm going insane...

Here is what I have:

```
// "from" is my element to check
if ( 
   ( typeof from.jqmData("external-page") == "undefined" 
            && from.parents('body').length == 1 ) 
     || 
   ( typeof from.jqmData("external-page") == "boolean" 
             && from.parents('body').length == 0 )
   ) {
     // do something    
     }
```

Can someone help me out and get me on the right track?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just do `if (... instanceOf A || ... instanceOf B) { ... }` ? [instanceOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: Not entirely sure what the issue is; you can check explicitly for `undefined` vs. `false` using `===`, beyond that it's just combinatorial logic.

Comment: @Andreas: thanks for instnaceOf. Never heard before.

Comment: Try to put the "most frequent/fastest" exclusion first as the first false in the "if" will allow it to skip the rest of the checking in a complex conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work:

```
if (from.parents('body').length === 0 || typeof from.jqmData('external-page') === 'undefined') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Ok. I got it! I needed to replace parentS with parent to make it work, but you got me on the right track!